# Poisson Brackets and Angular Momentum using Poisson Bracket algebra

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, hamiltonian-formalism, poisson-brackets

I've been trying to prove the identity for $\left\{L_i,L_j\right\}$ using only the algebra for the Poisson Brackets (of course I could do it by the definition with the derivatives and such, but where's the fun in that?).
Can you guys point out where I'm going wrong please?

$$\left\{L_i,L_j\right\} = \left\{\epsilon_{i\alpha\beta}q_\alpha p_\beta,\epsilon_{j\gamma\rho}q_\gamma p_\rho\right\}$$

$$\left\{L_i,L_j\right\} = \epsilon_{i\alpha\beta}\epsilon_{j\gamma\rho}\left\{q_\alpha p_\beta,q_\gamma p_\rho\right\}$$

$$\left\{L_i,L_j\right\} = \epsilon_{i\alpha\beta}\epsilon_{j\gamma\rho}\left(q_\alpha p_\rho\left\{p_\beta,q_\gamma \right\} + p_\beta q_\gamma\left\{x_\alpha,p_\rho\right\}\right)$$

$$\left\{L_i,L_j\right\} = \epsilon_{i\alpha\beta}\epsilon_{j\gamma\rho}\left(-q_\alpha p_\rho\delta_{\beta\gamma} + p_\beta q_\gamma\delta_{\alpha\rho}\right)$$

$$\left\{L_i,L_j\right\} = \epsilon_{i\alpha\beta}\epsilon_{j\beta\alpha}\left(-q_\alpha p_\alpha + p_\beta q_\beta\right)$$

Which cannot be right since we need to have cross terms. If that IS right, I cannot see how we get to the final answer from there.

Comment: Just to be clear, can you please explicitly state the identity you are trying to prove?

Comment: Maybe you will find what you need in the answers to this related question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47695/poisson-brackets-and-angular-momentum

Comment: Your last line is thoroughgoingly wrong and does not follow from the penultimate one. In fact, it has nonsensically doubly contracted indices....

Comment: Having deleted the last line, and contracted indices correctly, relabel and use the identity  $\epsilon_{i\alpha k}\epsilon_{j\rho k} +  \epsilon_{ij k}\epsilon_{\rho\alpha k} + \epsilon_{i\rho k}\epsilon_{\alpha j k} =0$, easy to prove from maximal antisymmetry of the free index pairs.

Comment: I see what's happening on the last line, the $\delta$ is not multipling all of the terms, so you cannot just "Replace" $\gamma$'s by $\beta$'s everywhere...